# Bionic Reading Formating

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I'm trying to format the entire text of a webpage to "[Bionic Reading](https://bionic-reading.com/br-method/)" from a button.

I saw an [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/erenkulaksiz/pen/GRQmYQq) that formatted raw text that you needed to identify, but I wish to automatically apply the function everywhere.

Basically, Bionic Reading is an accessible tool to format font so it's easier to read, especially for neurodivergent like ADHD. From my understanding, the list of criteria are:

- Wrap every word with span tag
- split the word in two
- Add a b tag with a class that will change the font-weight to bold
- Exclude numbers

You can test paragraphs here in the [Bionic Reading editing tool](https://app.bionic-reading.com/).

Currently my function **wraps word with `<span>` tag**, **splits the word in two** and **add a `<b class='font-weight-bold'>` tag** to go with the bootstrap class.

My main issue is that it doesn't ignore other tags inside paragraph or list tags, such as **`<br>`**, specification of span class and **`<a href="...">`**. I tried to exclude button tag, but when I have a button in a paragraph, it seems to ignore the paragraph outside of the button. The navbar made of list of icons seems to also output and replace icons to the full innerhtml.

I'm also using Vue and SCSS. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
/*----------
- Bionic Reading Accessibility
  ----------*/


  function addBionicReadingToPage() {
    const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p, li");
  
    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
      const words = paragraphs[i].innerHTML.split(" ");
      let formattedText = "";
  
      for (let j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        const halfLength = Math.ceil(words[j].length / 2);
        const aTag = paragraphs[i].querySelector(":root > p > a");
  
        // Check if the current word is inside a <button> tag
        const isInsideButton =
          paragraphs[i].querySelectorAll("button").length > 0 &&
          paragraphs[i]
            .querySelectorAll("button")
            .some((button) =>
              button.contains(paragraphs[i].querySelectorAll("b")[j])
            );
  
        // Check if the current word is inside an <li> tag inside an element with the "navbar" class
        const isInsideNavbar =
          paragraphs[i].querySelectorAll(".nav-item a").length > 0 &&
          paragraphs[i]
            .querySelectorAll(".nav-item a")[0]
            .contains(paragraphs[i].querySelectorAll("b")[j]);
  
        // Check if the current word is inside an <a> tag inside a <p> tag
        const formattedWord =
          aTag && aTag.contains(document.querySelector(":root > p > a > " + words[j]))
            ? words[j]
            : words[j].replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")
            ? "<span>" +
             "<b class='font-weight-bold'>" +
              words[j].substring(0, halfLength) +
              "</b>" +
              words[j].substring(halfLength)+
              "</span>"
            : words[j];
  
        formattedText += formattedWord + " ";
      }
  
      paragraphs[i].innerHTML = formattedText;
    }
  }
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,500,300italic,500italic,700italic,900,300);

html,
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.chat-picture img{
max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addBionicReadingToPage()">Click me</button>

<p>Bionic Reading is a new method facilitating the reading process by guiding the eyes through text with artificial fixation points. As a result, the reader is only focusing on the highlighted initial letters and lets the brain center complete the word.</p>

<ul>
<li>List of item 1</li>
<li>List of something 2</li>
<li>Another list of something testing 3</li>
</ul>


      <section id="cl-02" class="mod-1 py-5">
        <div class="container">           

          <div class="chat-item chat-bubble-right mb-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-end">
              <div class="col-9 col-lg-5">
                <div class="chat-bubble">
                  <p id="chatQuestion1" class="mb-0"><span class="sr-only">Bruno speaking. </span>Hey Mijin, I like your
                    poster! Nice work!<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 chat-picture">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1345336329/photo/orange-and-domestic-cat.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=ll7YVHEhvDc06D7WeItYrrgNeheiDJox0Gang6rI58A=" alt="Bruno" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-item chat-bubble-left mb-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 chat-picture">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1348266054/photo/bengal-cat-head-with-green-eyes-close-up-on-a-white-background.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=QUVbZ1cmXt0P1ofGy3zUoDhHcwG1rO_dksEHG7xUczU=" alt="Mijin" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="col-9 col-lg-5">
                <div class="chat-bubble">
                  <p class="mb-0"><span class="sr-only">Mijin speaking. </span>Thanks Bruno, I like it too!<br>
                    No. As it says, <b>everyone</b> Proin maximus, metus eget auctor suscipit, eros odio congue neque, commodo consectetur dolor purus a est.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-item chat-bubble-right mb-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-end">
              <div class="col-9 col-lg-5">
                <div class="chat-bubble">
                  <p id="chatQuestion1" class="mb-0"><span class="sr-only">Bruno speaking. </span>Oh, I guess not. Would
                    you give me a refresher?</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 chat-picture">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1345336329/photo/orange-and-domestic-cat.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=ll7YVHEhvDc06D7WeItYrrgNeheiDJox0Gang6rI58A=" alt="Bruno" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="chat-item chat-bubble-left mb-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 chat-picture">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1348266054/photo/bengal-cat-head-with-green-eyes-close-up-on-a-white-background.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=QUVbZ1cmXt0P1ofGy3zUoDhHcwG1rO_dksEHG7xUczU=" alt="Mijin" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="col-9 col-lg-5">
                <div class="chat-bubble">
                  <p class="mb-0"><span class="sr-only">Mijin speaking. </span>Of course! Let's go have a coffee and
                    talk about it.<br>In 30 minutes, you'll be a Maecenas placerat!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </section>
```